# Join two pyarrow tables

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow, orc

I have orc with data as after.

Table A:

```
Name    age     school      address      phone
tony    12      havard      UUU          666
tommy   13      abc         Null         Null
john    14      cde         Null         Null
john    14      cde         Null         Null
```

Table B:
Name    address     phone

```
tommy   USD         345   
john    ASA         444
```

Expected table after join:
Name    age     school      address      phone

```
tony    12      havard      UUU          666
tommy   13      abc         USD          345
john    14      cde         ASA          444
john    14      cde         ASA          444
```

How  I can do it with pyarrow or pandas
Name of table a is not unique, Name of table B is unique.

Comment: what should happen if two names are the same? What should happen if some is left without address in the end? What should happen if A and B have a different address for the same person?

Comment: + Name is unique
+ A and B have a different address for the same person ->B will overwrite data of A

Comment: sorry, name of table a not unique, I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dfA.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
dfA.update(dfB.set_index('Name'))
dfA.reset_index()
```

Note: this 'Name' column should have unique values as mentioned by @Antti Haapala -- Слава Україні

When A and B have different values of 'Address' and 'Phone' for one 'Name', table A's values will be updated by values from table B

Comment: ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels

Comment: The column has duplicate values

Comment: sorry, name of table a not unique, I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

In pyarrow, starting with 8.0.0, you can do this with a combination of join and coalesce.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.compute as pc

table_a = pa.Table.from_pydict({
    "name": ["tony", "tommy", "john"],
    "age": [12, 13, 14],
    "school": ["havard", "abc", "cde"],
    "address": ["UUU", None, None],
    "phone": [666, None, None]
  })

table_b = pa.Table.from_pydict({
    "name": ["tommy", "john"],
    "address": ["USD", "ASA"],
    "phone": [345, 444]
  })

combined = table_a.join(table_b, 'name', right_suffix='_r')

coalesced_addrs = pc.coalesce(combined.column('address_r'), combined.column('address'))
coalesced_phone = pc.coalesce(combined.column('phone_r'), combined.column('phone'))

result = pa.Table.from_pydict({
    'name': combined.column('name'),
    'age': combined.column('age'),
    'school': combined.column('school'),
    'address': coalesced_addrs,
    'phone': coalesced_phone
  })

print(result)
```

Comment: sorry, name of table a not unique, I updated the question

Comment: 'pyarrow.lib.Table' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: maybe im using 7.0.0 version https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/

Comment: 8.0.0 has not released yet.  It will release in the next few weeks.  I will delete my answer until then.

Comment: Well that didn't take long :)

Comment: If the column is not unique then I'm pretty sure pyarrow's join will give you all combinations.  E.g. if you have 3 "tommy" rows in table_a and 4 "tommy" rows in table_b then you will end up with 12 "tommy" rows in the combined table.